# Apollo Client 3: How to implement caching on client side for graphql interfaces?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I have a case where I have an `interface`, which has different `type` implementations defined in graphql. I may not be able to share the exact code. But the case looks something like:

```
interface Character {
  name: String!
}
```

```
type Human implements Character {
  name: String!
  friends: [Character]
}

type Droid implements Character {
  name: String!
  material: String
}
```

There is query which returns either `Human` or `Droid` type in response.

Response may contain something like:

```
{
  name: 'Human_01',
  friends: []
  __typename: 'Human'
}
```

or

```
{
  name: 'Droid_01',
  material: 'Aluminium'
  __typename: 'Droid'
}
```

I am using Apollo Client 3 on client side for querying the data and have fragments for these like:

```
fragment Human on Human {
 friends
}

fragment Droid on Droid {
 material
}

fragment Character on Character {
  name
  ...Human
  ...Droid
}
```

I am querying for the `Character` data as:

```
 character {
  ...Character
 }
```

Since, this is the case of `interface`, and as defined in the docs for Apollo client 3, we need to use `possibleTypes` in order to match the fragments in such cases. For caching purpose, I have defined InMemoryCache as:

```
new InMemoryCache({ possibleTypes: { Character: ['Human', 'Droid'] } })
```

The primary key field for a `Character` implementation is the `name` field, which I need to use in order to store its value in cache.

In Apollo client 3, it is mentioned to use `typePolicies` for defining `keyFields` for a type.

So, I need to ask as to whether I should define, type policy for both type implementations, specifying `keyFields` as `name` in both cases like:

```
new InMemoryCache({ 
    possibleTypes: { Character: ['Human', 'Droid'] }, 
    typePolicies: { Human: { keyFields: ['name'] }, Droid: { keyFields: ['name'] } } 
});
```

In my example, I have provided only 2 such type implementations but there can be `n` number of type implementations corresponding to `Character` interface. So, in that case I will need to define `keyFields` as `name` in `typePolicies` for all the `n` type implementations.

So, does there exist any better way of implementing caching wrt these types of  `interface` implementations ?

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Inheritance of type and field policies](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/pull/7065) is coming in the next minor version of `@apollo/client`, v3.3!

You can try it out now by installing `@apollo/client@3.3.0-beta.5`.

To stay up to date on the progress of the v3.3 release, see [this pull request](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/pull/7015).

Comment: Thanks for the help!  
Will definitely check this out !